# replace observableArray with new data

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I have a viewmodel like

```
   AppViewModel = {
    agent : ko.observableArray([ {
        name : 'test',
        age  : '23'             
    }])         
};
```

My json data comes like

```
{"agent":[{"name":"john","age":"23"},{"name":"conor","age":"23"}]}
```

for ajaxcall evry 3 sec

How to replace the view model with new data

I tried

```
success : function(responseData) {
    var data = ko.toJS(responseData);
    //AppViewModel.agent.push(data);
     AppViewModel.agent.replace(agent,data);
}
```

but doest work.

Comment: `push()` is for arrays, it adds a new items to the array.

Comment: @Sébastien sorry,i corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is set the observable

```
success : function(responseData) {
    var data = ko.toJS(responseData);
    AppViewModel.agent(data.agent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just assign new data to array:

```
success : function(responseData) {
    var data = ko.toJS(responseData);
    AppViewModel.agent(data);
}
```