# map varying json data to observable array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I have a viewmodel like

```
AppViewModel = {
    agent : ko.observableArray([ {
        name : 'test',
        age  : '23'             
    }])         
};
```

My json data comes like

```
{"agent":[{"name":"john","age":"23"},{"name":"conor","age":"23"}]}
```

for ajaxcall every 3 sec

I could able to replace the observable array like [from [here]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20091586/replace-observablearray-with-new-data)

```
success : function(responseData) {
    var data = ko.toJS(responseData);  
     AppViewModel.agent(data.agent);
}
```

Some times the json data comes like

```
{"agent":[{"name":"john"}]}
```

without age, in this case the incomplete data stays with the observable array

and getting script error as

`'age' is undefined` in databinding

even after new response arrives like `{"agent":[{"name":"john","age":"23"}]}`

I want whole obsevable array to replaced with new data.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

[image]

DataBinding:

```
<!-- ko foreach: agent-->
    <tr>                                
        <td style="font-weight:bold;" data-bind="text: name"></td>      
        <td style="font-weight:bold;" data-bind="text: age"></td>
    </tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Where do you get the error in your javascript or in render process ? Can you post your view ?

Comment: @Damien I have given the View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you prefix your property with the `$data` special [binding context](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) property then KO won't complain if the given property does not exists.

So if you write `$data.age` then you don't get an error if the server sends an object without the `age` property:

```
<tr>
    <td style="font-weight:bold;" data-bind="text: $data.name"></td>
    <td style="font-weight:bold;" data-bind="text: $data.age"></td>
</tr>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JYGc5/).